# execute multiple cmd command in a single line

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, cmd, command-line

I have multiple commands and I wanted to execute them in a single line using Process. The first command is using a `For loop`.

```
for /f ... do xxxx...
```

then after finishing the command above execute another multiple commands.

```
& [command] & [command] & [command] & [command]
```

I understand the use of `&` and `&&` operator so I tried the following command and no result.

```
for /f ... do xxxx... & [command] & [command] & [command] & [command]
```

To summarize the issue, the problem occurred after finishing the `for loop`, the second command is not executed which should be executed with or without error because of `&` operator.

My current solution is to use a separated process method and call after finishing the `for loop` command.

```
private string void cmd_command(){
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/K";
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.Start();

    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"for /f ... do xxxx..."); 
    process.StandardInput.Flush();
    process.StandardInput.Close();
    process.WaitForExit();

    string response = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(response);

    if(response.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(expectedOutput)){
        //call second multiple command
        return next_cmd_command();
    }

    return null;
}

private string next_cmd_command(){
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/K";
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.Start();

    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"[command] & [command] & [command] & [command]"); 
    process.StandardInput.Flush();
    process.StandardInput.Close();
    process.WaitForExit();

    string response = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(response);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Have you got the command to work from a cmd prompt outside your program?

Comment: Yes, it is working. I actually built the command through cmd outside my program.

Comment: what happens if you dont use writeline, and put it on the actual command line

Comment: I'll try. By the way, I have a thought that it could be the loop is not breaking and keep on re-executing the command. I'll try to put an `exit /b` at the end of the commands and see if it works.

Comment: Your command line executes the `for` loop and does *everything after `do`* for each iteration.. Use `(for /f .... do xxxx) & command & command...`

Comment: @Stephan -  I tried it, but no it's not working. However, I tried adding `exit /b` at the end of the command and it works, but I have a doubt with the command. Not sure if this is the right way.

Comment: Are you aware that `cmd /k` keeps the command prompt open until you explicitly close it (with `exit` or manually closing it)? (great for troubleshooting, but `WaitForExit` will wait for that to happen). When done with troubleshooting, change to `cmd /c`.

Comment: @Stephen - yep I know, and correct, I actually use it just for troubleshooting. I will use ` /C` on production.